# tabbarのアイコンをオリジナルのものに変更したい

Tags: monaca, 画像, font

いつもお世話になっております。
アイコンをオリジナルで作ってやろうと思っているのですが、カスタマイズの仕方が上手く分かりません。

当初考えていたのが、ionからダウンロードしたファイルを使って、自分で作成したiconを既存の使わないiconと置き換える予定だったのですが上手くいきませんでした。
ionのファイル→http://ionicons.com./
おそらく画像ではなく、フォントとして認識しているようなのですが。。。

アイコンのカスタマイズに詳しい方はどなたか教えていただけますでしょうか。

やり方はどのような風でもかまいませんが、作成したアイコンも別のアイコンと同様に色が変えられると嬉しいです。

```js
(function() {
    ons.bootstrap()
})();
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <ons-page>
      <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="home"
            label="fontawsomeのhome"
            page="homeNavi.html"
            active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="ion-ios-location"
            label="ionのlocation"
            page="commentNavi.html"
            ></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="original"
            label="オリジナルのicon"
            page="settingNavi.html"
            ></ons-tabbar-item>
      </ons-tabbar>
    </ons-page>




  <ons-template id="homeNavi.html">
    <ons-navigator var="homeNavi" page="page1.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="commentNavi.html">
    <ons-navigator var="commentNavi" page="page2.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="settingNavi.html">
    <ons-navigator var="settingNavi" page="page3.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <br />
      <ons-button ng-click="homeNavi.pushPage('page1-2.html')">
        Push New Page
      </ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 2</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page3.html">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 3</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page1-2.html">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">New Page</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <br />
      <ons-button ng-click="homeNavi.popPage();">
        Pop Page
     </ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-template>  
</body>
```

Comment: 画像ファイルを設定したい、ということですか？

Comment: @ ita_3y はい、画像が設定できればと思っております。最悪、フォントとして置き代えれたらと思っております。

Answer (score 1):

`ons-tab`から`icon`と`label`を削除して配下にhtmlを書けばいけるようです。
色変更, 位置の調整等はcssで何とかなるかなと思います。

```js
ons.bootstrap();
```

```css
.my-icon {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active > .tab-bar-inner > .my-icon {
  background-color: #eff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <ons-tabbar var="tab">
    <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true">
    </ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="comments.html">
      <div class="my-icon"><img src="" alt="オリジナルアイコン" /></div>
    </ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="tags.html" label="Tags" icon="ion-ios-pricetag">
    </ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="settings.html" label="Settings" icon="ion-ios-cog">
    </ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
</body>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Home</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Home Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="comments.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Comments</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Comment Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="tags.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Tags</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Tags Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Settings</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Settings Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>
```